# Text to columns with structure: Apple David 1234 5679 2456

Tags: excel, function

I want to separate data in one cell into three cells.

That is, the data structure is

```
"Fruit Name"+certain spaces+"Name"+certain spaces+"Numbers".
```

And what I what is

```
Fruit Name
Name
Numbers
```

in three separate cells.

[image]

I know the built-in function of excel `Text to columns` can put fixed width to do this function. However, the word may be spitted into two different cells. Ex. `Apple` > `App` in one cell and `le` in another cell.

So, I want functions to do the task.

In `F5`, I use `=mid(E5,1,find(" ",E5))`.

However, I do not know how to proceed in `G5` and `H5` for `David` and `1236 4566 078 7888`.

I appreciate you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Update!

I fixed the formula for column F from the original post because it still included the space after `Fruit Name`.

The formula for column G finds the spaces on the left of `Name` and trims them, and finds the next occurrence of a space character to mark the end of `Name`. And for column H, it finds the value in column G, skips it, then trims the leading spaces.

For column F:

```
=MID(E1, 1, FIND(" ", E1) - 1)
```

For column G:

```
=MID(TRIM(MID(E1, FIND(" ", E1), LEN(E1))), 1, FIND( " ", TRIM(MID(E1, FIND(" ", E1), LEN(E1)))) - 1)
```

For column H:

```
=TRIM(MID(E1, FIND(G1, E1) + LEN(G1), LEN(E1)))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in my situation, the number of spaces do vary due to the person who input the data. I wonder if there are functions which can work for this.

Comment: Thanks again. I have found that if the number of spaces varies, your solution works. However, I have just found that the inputer used `tab` and `spaces` to separate the data. May I ask if there are any scripts to capture only the `text` (non-space objects) only? Sorry for being so trouble.

Comment: @RowenChumacera - I tried your solution but its not working for all combinations like : `Apple Michael 456 456 456` and `Pear Johnson 1234 4567 8912` all with single spaces.

Comment: @Mrig thanks for pointing that out. I'll work on it on Monday.

Comment: @nam sorry, I'm not sure how the tab character can be placed in an Excel cell. If that's the case, the value next to the tab character should be in the next column.

Answer (score 0):

This UDF can help you:

```
Function GetWord(MyString As String, WordNum As Long)
MyString = Trim(Replace(MyString, Chr(32), " "))
Do Until Len(MyString) = Len(Replace(MyString, "  ", " "))
    MyString = Replace(MyString, "  ", " ")
Loop
GetWord = Split(MyString," ")(WordNum - 1)
End Function
```

Use it like this `=GetWord(A1,2)` where A1 has your text and 2 is the word number you want to retrieve.